# Cryptix setup with java-bridge on ubuntu is throwing algorithm not found error

Tags: java, php, cryptography, jvm, php-java-bridge

I am trying to setup a payment gateway. For which I have setup a java bridge as the portal is a java machine. My setup is following :

1. Apache server
2. Tomcat 7
3. Java-6-open jdk

following is error from catalina.out

```
PospostSSL><Exception in encrypting data. algorithm DES/ECB is
 not available from provider Cryptix>
<PostLib><postSSL><SFAApplicationException. Error while encrypting
data. Transaction cannot be processed.>
```

I have placed the cryptix32.jar in shared folder of tomcat. Also adding or removing line from java.security for cryptix provider is also not having any effect.

Please can any one tell me what needs to be done to get this error out.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to set up a payment portal using [DES](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/05-9945-DES-Withdrawl.pdf) and [Cryptix](http://www.cryptix.org/)? Then you are proposing to use Apache - probably with [OpenSSL](http://heartbleed.com/) - as  proxy. A proxy to a Java version that is basically [end of life](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html). And you are using one without commercial support.

`"DES/ECB"` is part of the standard SunJCE provider as well. No need for Cryptix there.

Please stop resurrecting the dead and go do something else.

Comment: actually packages provided by third party uses that i cant help it.

Comment: i think i will create a proxy tunnel to one of my server which already have this setup. Cant seem to get anywhere with setting up this thing.

Comment: Maybe I have less to loose, but I would flat out refuse to implement a protocol and software that is as completely out of date as this one. That would put my professionalism on the line. Unless it was requested by a museum of course. Setting up a proxy would at least keep you to one outdated implementation, so that sounds more sane than trying to get it running another time.

Comment: setting up proxy tunnel worked wonder if any one is struggling with same issue they can get the work done by following command : ssh -TCN -L port_local:localhost:port_server user@server_address